# How do I enter I/O ports during TempleOS boot?

Tags: boot, keyboard, port, input, templeos

I've been trying to try TempleOS. 
When it starts booting up, it asks me to supply I/O ports and explains how to find those ports from Windows and Linux. I think I've found the ports it wants.

I seem unable to actually enter the port numbers. None of the keyboard keys will work. I've tried it on several computers, with no luck. Just how am I meant to enter the port numbers?

Here is the picture of the message that I get from TempleOS. 
*Note: this picture is taken from the **Shrine distribution**,
but the message is nearly identical to that of the main TempleOS.*
[image]

Comment: Oh man. TempleOS questions here tend to be fraught, and the author was quite literally a little.. crazy. What sort of keyboard? I doubt a USB keyboard would work. Have you tried setting the keyboard to legacy mode? You quite literally want an older 32 bit machine with legacy bios and OS/2 for this kind of thing.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek For the Keyboard, I've tried it with a built in laptop keyboard and other USB keyboards. Legacy mode **is** enabled in my BIOS.                                              

I'm not sure what you said about wanting a 32 bit machine is correct, When Temple OS is booted from a 32 bit machine it will give you a message saying you need a 64 bit machine in order to run temple OS. And I’m pretty sure latest version of Temple OS was released in 2017 so I would have thought it can handle USB keyboards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention in a comment that you are using "a built in laptop keyboard and other USB keyboards".

In an article entitled ["Why Not More"](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Doc/WhyNotMore.html), it is stated:

> Adding a USB driver would be really ugly with UHCI, EHCI, OHCI, USB1, USB2, 
>   USB3, ICH6, ICH7, ICH8, ICH9, ICH10, ICH11, ICH12, boot mode and regular mode 
>   for keyboard/mouse and a diversity of HID reports.  It's hopeless.  I could 
>   never offer anything but crappy, limited support and it would just add a ton of 
>   crappy code that mostly didn't work.  What would I gain?  Nothing.  A keyboard 
>   or mouse would not be improved.  Solid State USB drives would be really nice, 
>   but it's not going to happen.

It thus appears that USB is simply not supported in TempleOS. The best thing to do would probably be to find a PC with a legacy PS/2 port or run TempleOS in a virtual environment that can emulate a PS/2 keyboard. In another answer, Evan Carroll also [concludes](https://superuser.com/a/1328149/629239) that TempleOS requires PS/2 support, based on another part of the cited document.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your answer! I've tried it with a PS/2 keyboard and it's working. Thanks!

Comment: @LachlanMcIlroy you are very welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: This is a really good answer, it's nice to be able to see other contribute to our community professionally and fairly.